# How do I create a layout that can contain buttons in PyQt5?

Tags: python, user-interface, layout, pyqt5

I am trying to create a window that has a banner with two buttons underneath. I would like the layout to be like this:

[image]

Where I could put buttons in the green and blue boxes and an image in the red box. How would you go about doing something like this?

Comment: Please show whatever code you have so far. What specific problems are you having when trying to create the layout?

Answer (score 0):

I think the fastest and easiest way is to use `Qt Designer`.

Once there, basically, create your window (`QWidget`for example) and define your layout `QVBoxLayout` or `QHBoxLayout` before adding your buttons`QPushButton` or images `QImage`or `QIcon`.

Answer (score 0):

```
    self.verticalLayoutWidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(borreme)
    self.verticalLayoutWidget.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(19, 30, 351, 111))
    self.verticalLayoutWidget.setObjectName("verticalLayoutWidget")
    self.verticalLayout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self.verticalLayoutWidget)
    self.verticalLayout.setObjectName("verticalLayout")
    self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.verticalLayoutWidget)
    self.label.setObjectName("label")
    self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.label)
    self.horizontalLayout = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout()
    self.horizontalLayout.setObjectName("horizontalLayout")
    self.pushButton_2 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.verticalLayoutWidget)
    self.pushButton_2.setObjectName("pushButton_2")
    self.horizontalLayout.addWidget(self.pushButton_2)
    self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.verticalLayoutWidget)
    self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
    self.horizontalLayout.addWidget(self.pushButton)
    self.verticalLayout.addLayout(self.horizontalLayout)
```

done by using qtdesigner and this

```
     pyuic5 borreme.ui -o borrreme.py
```